# Get multiline words <title></title> REGEX classic asp

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, asp-classic, regex-lookarounds

```
<title>

    Ask a Question - Stack Overflow Ask a Question - Stack Overflow

</title>
```

when i was try to catch title empty. my pattern is

```
<title[^>]*>([^<]+)</title>
```

how can i remove empty lines or catch only title text?.

thank you

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the server, or in JavaScript? It you're trying to do this is JavaScript, do you have to use a regular expression?

Comment: You won't be able to reliably parse HTML using a regular expression. You'll get better results with an HTML parser. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

[www.regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com/) is a great utility for answering these types of questions. The *m* flag on a RegEx object will catch multiple lines nicely. This should match everything in between the title tags in the first matching group, even if it's multi-line, I always use the *i* flag as well, just to handle the unknowns if you're working with 3rd party data:

```
/<title>([^<]+)<\/title>/im
```

If you'd like the whitepsace removed (i.e. trim), you could do something like:

```
/<title>(?:\s+)?([^<]+)(?:\s+)?<\/title>/im
```

In either case, your first match group should have what you'd like:

```
myText.match(/<title>(?:\s+)?([^<]+)(?:\s+)?<\/title>/im)[1]
```